# How to change keyboard mapping in recent X11?

Tags: x11

I have a laptop with a bad "enter" key. I think, mapping the right shift to Enter would be an useful compromis to make it again usable.

Some decades ago, there were some loadkeys or setxkb commands to change directly the keyboard mapping.

What could be done today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setxkb` should still work, though your desktop environment keyboard switching applet might interfere .

However, in your situation xcape (https://github.com/alols/xcape) should be better, you can keep the right shift being shift if pressed together with a different key, and  generate Enter if pressed on its own (I am using it to remap right shift to /, since my notebook's reduced keyboard lacks the separate / key and the right shift is at just the right place)